# Meaning of tourage

Tags: meaning

Lionel Richie and Mariah Carey will be going on a tour on summer. Lionel Richie says about Mariah Carey that "She doesn't come with entourage, she comes with 'tourage'." What does tourage mean in this context? I read somewhere that it's the short form of 'entourage' but in this case it has to differ somehow because it's used in lieu of it.

Comment: This is clearl an invented word, and determining the meaning will require some context. Please [edit] to include the source and the surrounding text when you can.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would assume it means the opposite, or near opposite of entourage, as it is used in lieu of the original word.

"Tourage" is a made-up word, invented by the author to emphasize a point.

I don't know if you read this somewhere, or if you wrote this sentence yourself, but I assume it means that Mariah Carey came with nobody else, as opposed to coming with an entourage, a group of people.

Comment: Doesn't it sound like a pun on tour? Not just a normal following, but a jumbo tour size following.

Answer (score 0):

Marie Carey travels with a large staff.  Lionel Carey is saying that's it's not just an "entourage"--it's more than that. Apparently she travels with 100 people

Here's a clip from an Entertainment comment section debating her New Year's Eve performanceto give you an idea:

> Yes, she is a diva,but I was surprised how well she comes across in
>   the show. She is bright,intelligent and caring.The problem is she has
>   surrounded herself with high-drama queens and losers. Every one of them
>   taking advantage of her. Her manageress is a nightmare. She has a
>   dancer she hasn't seen in 10 years and he is trying to act like they
>   are best friends. He's pathetic. More than anything I feel sorry for
>   her living her life surrounded by a 100 people who want something from
>   her. I'm sure she is used to it,but it's still sad.